# wso2 Identity server: how to get user info via OAuth2.0 token and OpenID token?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I use wso2 identity server to be the key manager of wso2 API-M cluster.

Now user can log in API-M via Google account(OpenID) or Facebook(OAuth2.0) account.

What my question is:

Whatever user log in the system via OAuth2.0 or OpenID, I'll get the token which is verified via identity server.

Now I wanna get the user info (id, from which social service...etc) via their token but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by accessing the userinfo endpoint with the received access token.

The curl command is as follows:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 4164157d677a6cd3a22e26e24c30135d" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

As the response, the WSO2 Identity Server returns a JSON with user claims.

Refer [[OpenID Connect Basic Client Profile with WSO2 Identity Server](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/OpenID+Connect+Basic+Client+Profile+with+WSO2+Identity+Server)] for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Is OAuth2.0 the same way to get user info?